# Calculate cos 43 with an error of less than 7/20,000

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My question is on the heading. How can i calculate cos 43 with an error of less than 7/20,000. 43 is degree not radians.

Comment: Do you mean manually?

Comment: Have you tried using a Taylor polynomial?

Comment: What is the context here? Are you looking for by-hand methods or an algorithm for computer implementation?

Comment: Yes manually. And no i'm not looking for an algorithm it's my homework i've figure out myself for my bachelor program.

Comment: I might add that there's a trick relevant here that isn't mentioned in the answer to the linked question, namely, expanding the Taylor series around a convenient nonzero point, in this case $a = 45^\circ = \frac{\pi}{4}$. Then, the distance $|x - a|$ in the usual Taylor error bound is small, $2^\circ = \frac{\pi}{90}$, so we'd expect to need fewer terms of this expansion than that about $a = 0$.

Comment: 43 degrees or radians?